# Create Python package locally to be installed with pip

Tags: python, pip, package, setup.py

I am writing my first sharable python module. For IP reasons, I am not going to make it public, but I want to use it on my machine locally, and any machines that I want to work on. My goal then is to use the power of `pip` to automatically check for certain required installs, etc.

I need, in step by step detail, a guide on how to properly package this thing, package it, and then install it with `pip`.  Imagine that my directory, and the important files look like this:

```
project_name/
    setup.py
    package/
        __init__.py
        core.py
```

Here `core.py` is a file that looks something like:

```
## core.py

# Imports
import blah blah blah

# main thing is just a class
class Thing:
    A class that I care about that has modules, etc.
```

`__init__.py` is totally empty, and my `setup.py` looks like this:

```
## setup.py

import io
import os

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

with io.open(os.path.join(dir, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='project',
    version='1.0',
    description='Tool to share',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://github.com/private_directory',
    author='Me',
    author_email='my_email@place.org',
    license='GNU',
    install_requires=['pandas>=0.25', 'lxml','matplotlib'],
    python_requires='>=3',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

I try and run:

```
>>python setup.py bdist_wheel
>>pip install dist/project-1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Where the last thing is the path to the wheel file, and nothing happens! It runs but when I use `conda list` nothing is there. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try `pip list`? I don't see what this has to do with `conda`.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just `pip install -e` here instead of generating a wheel.

Comment: I tried `pip install -e` here. Do i need to create the wheels file first? and I would like the package to appear when I run `conda list`, just as other packages that install through `pip` would.

Comment: I am partway there. I can use it with `pip install -e` but it it is dependent on file location, it does not install a copy into my conda root. Basically, I noticed that I can successfully install this, but then if I delete the folder (let's say I have it in my downloads and then I remove it), then it no longer appears. This begs the question, what does the `-e` do?

Comment: _and I would like the package to appear when I run conda list, just as other packages that install through pip would._ How many packages are you installing using pip in Conda environments?

Comment: Anaconda has a different package format than wheels. If you want to build a conda package, refer to [conda tutorials](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html).